# relative error and boundary in calculating exponentiation

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

Here is a textbook question from "A First Course in Numerical Methods", book of the course "Numerical Analysis and Computational Mathematics". Since i am new to the topic i couldn't find a way for this question. Thanks in advance. ([question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TnT7.jpg)):

> Consider exponentiation, which is performed according to the formula
>   $$x^y = e^{y\ln x},\quad x > 0.$$
>   Estimate the relative error in calculating $x^y$ in floating point, assuming $$\mathrm{fl}(\ln z) = (\ln z)(1+ \epsilon), \quad |\epsilon| ≤ \eta,$$ and that everything else is exact. Show that the sort of bound we have for elementary operations and for $\ln$ does not hold for exponentiation when $x^y$ is very large.

Comment: Do not link to the question, write the problem here. Then fix your grammar to the best of your ability and you will have more luck getting help.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the property $e^{x+y}=e^x e^y$ of the exponential function
$$\mathrm{fl}(x^y) = e ^{y\;\mathrm{fl}(\ln x)}  = 
e ^{y\,((\ln x) (1 + \epsilon))} = 
e ^{y\,(\ln x + \epsilon \ln x))} =
e ^{y \ln x} \cdot e^{y \epsilon \ln x} =  x^y \cdot e^{y \epsilon \ln x}
$$
So the relative error is 
$$\frac{\left|x^y - \mathrm{fl} (x^y)\right|}{\left|x^y\right|}
=\frac{\left|x^y - x^y\cdot e^{y \epsilon \ln x}\right|}{\left|x^y\right|}
= \left|1- e^{y \epsilon \ln x}\right|$$
which is unbounded. For not too large $x,y$ you have
$$\left|1- e^{y \epsilon \ln x}\right|\approx 
\left|1- (1 + y\epsilon \ln x+O(\epsilon^2)\right| \approx
\left| y\epsilon \ln x\right|
$$

Comment: Sir, how did you write the part after the first ≈ sign?

Comment: These are the first two  terms of the Taylor expansion for small $\epsilon$
$$e^{y \epsilon \ln x} = 1+\epsilon y\ln x +\frac{1}{2}(\epsilon y \ln x)^2 
+\frac{1}{6}(\epsilon y \ln x)^3
+O(\epsilon^3)$$

Comment: Thanks, but why the question says that "that sort of bound we have for elementary operations and for ln does not hold for exponentiation when x^y is very large." What does it tell?

Comment: And a key question: You said ".. which is unbounded". But you know Floating Point Representation Error Theorem, relative error <= β^(1−t) for chopping, and (1/2)*β^(1−t) for rounding. Why didn't we calculate these boundaries?

Comment: I do not know why they excatly use that wording, but for the other elementary operations you have
$\mathrm{fl}(op) = op \cdot ( 1 + \epsilon_{op})$ with $\epsilon_{op}$ of order machine epsilon. For $x^y$ and double precision $x=500, y=100, \epsilon =2^{-53}$ you get with the above $$\epsilon_{x^y} \approx y \ln x \approx 621$$ 
Actual computation gives $151$, and for $x=500.01$ the actual value is $248$.

Regarding *unbounded*: This is trivial by looking at the function, in practice you get a floating overflow, e.g. for $500^{120} \approx 0.75\cdot 10^{324}$

Comment: That helped. Thanks a lot!